# Show DIVs with greatest value

Tags: jquery, external

Ok, so I'm making a "tip of the week" slider. Basically it's for my client, which is the reason I'd need to simplify the posting process as much as possible.

Right now it is just a slider for 4 divs: http://juuso.kivinen.org/tofw/
That is not the most recent version, because I haven't had time to update it yet(server ver.).

So basically(sorry for the long intro) my question is:
How can I make jquery load the first 4 divs from an external html file?
Or should I move to php?

The basic structure of my code would be:

```
<div id="slider">
 <div id="row">
  <div id="EXTERNAL CONTENT1"></div>
 </div>
<div id="row">
 <div id="EXTERNAL CONTENT2"></div>
</div>
<div id="row">
 <div id="EXTERNAL CONTENT3"></div>
</div>
<div id="row">
 <div id="EXTERNAL CONTENT4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: non-unique id is a bad idea.  will this be a cross-domain html file?

Comment: Actually non-unique "id" values are invalid markup, in addition to being a bad idea :-)  You should use a "class" value to categorize elements. The "id" attribute is for assigning **unique** identifiers.

Comment: you are advised not to use same `id` s which may make your DOM selectors fail (if you are using jQuery) also spaces in ids are not encouraged..

Comment: Yeah, I've have unique ID's, just wrote the example fast, so it doesn't match the actual code. The ID's are row1, row2 etc. sorry. and no, it will not be a cross-domain file, I know it wouldn't work..

Comment: Just a heads-up for you, on Chrome accessing your site brings up the warning: "This site is attempting to download multiple files. Do you want to allow this?" I'm not sure quite *why* that's happening, but it might be worth fixing whatever's causing it, since, personally, I always click 'no' and then **close** that page, quickly.

Comment: Your Question's title doesn't have any relation with your queation.. next time try to be bit more sensible

Comment: Well it kinda does. I was referring to the most recent divs/ the divs on top. Thats what I meant with greatest value. And thanks David, it seems to be the bandcamp player that acts weirdly.And what about if the external file contains all the "tips of the week"? So that it'd always load the 4 most recent? aka the 4 on the top of the html

Comment: For anybody interested, I got it to work, thank you all! It now loads all it content externally :) http://juuso.kivinen.org/tofw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt/) and [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#container').load('path/to/page.html #divContainer div:lt(4)');
```

Demonstration of concept: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/play/loadDemo2.html (original version: http//:davidrhysthomas.co.uk/play/loadDemo.html).

Comment: Thanks dude! Your example didn't quite work on my computer, dunno why. I chose your answer because you included the it(4) part. I used :nth child, but you gave me the idea. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Did you want the *fourth* `div`? I read your question as wanting the first four, for some reason. Oops. But yeah: [`nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) would certainly work for selecting the fourth =) And thank you for the accept and up-vote! =)

Comment: I wanted the first four to show up in the slider, so it would be easy to update. http://juuso.kivinen.org/tofw

Answer (score 1):

Without more information a complete answer isn't possible, but you should look at the .load() method for jQuery. You are able to load partial sections of external files. [`http://api.jquery.com/load/`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

for example:

```
$('#EXTERNAL_CONTENT1').load('tips.html #external1')
```

What will the structure of the file you want to load from look like? Is your client going to be continually appending to that file?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have set up some code in your server to serve the `EXTERNALCONTENT`

then

```
$.get("urlToGetEXTERNALCONTENT",function(data){
$("#EXTERNALCONTENT4").html(data);
});
```

Comment: i thought it's obvious that you should write separate codes for each DIV.. just saved some space

Comment: And what about if the external file contains all the "tips of the week"? So that it'd always load the 4 most recent? aka the 4 on the top of the html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ".load()" method to pluck content out of a loaded document. In your case:

```
$('#placeToPutStuff').load(yourUrl + ' #slider', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I thought of using load, just didn't look into it yet. Thanks for the tip. The external file will be structured into divs. And I'll just make the jquery load each part for each div etc. Thanks, I probably figured it out now. I'll give you the points later.